# geom_segment() different start values on the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(int_times,aes(x=-stim ,y=num,colour=gene)) +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks=int_times$num,labels=int_times$gene) +
       geom_segment(aes(xend=stim,ystart=num,yend=num),size=5) +
       xlab('IW (min)') +
       ylab('Genes') +
       opts(title='multi')
```

int_times:

```
  gene    lag   stim  num
 Pcsk1  46.53 173.53    1
serpin2 83.00 208.02    2
  Bdnf  33.00 277.02    3
 Fosl2  49.00 266.03    4
  Pax1  33.59 243.56    5
  Acan 188.49  70.30    6
 Pthlh  50.00 271.45    7
   Crh  35.00 359.06    8
```

this is what I have right now
[image]

what I would like though is for the y values 'stim' to start at their corresponding 'lag' instead of all starting at 0.

i thought you could just do a xstart=lag in aes() of geom_segment, but that isn't working for me.

any help?

Comment: `xend=length(stim)` is sort of nonsense. You're telling ggplot to end each bar at the length of a 1 element vector, hence all the bars extend to 1 (not zero, as you question implies).

Comment: ya, i fixed that but i'm not sure how to incorporate a start value here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (I named the data something different when I imported it):

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=-stim ,y=num,colour=gene)) +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks=dat$num,labels=dat$gene) +
       geom_segment(aes(xend=lag,ystart=num,yend=num),size=5) +
       xlab('IW (min)') +
       ylab('Genes') +
       opts(title='multi')
```

[image]

But it's still very unclear from your question what you intend. You refer to the start and end `y` values, but surely you mean `x`? The start values for the bars are being inherited from the `-stim` passed to `x` in `ggplot`. I simply passed `lag` as the end points.

If you really want the bars to start at `lag`, then you should remove `x = -stim` from `ggplot` and simply pass start and end values in `geom_segment`. (In fact, that probably a good idea in general.)

Comment: this is good, the only thing I changed was xend=-lag. when I do this though 0 is not included in the xaxis. would something like scale_x_continuous(limits(0,length(....?)) work?

Comment: @Doug It would probably be simpler to just use `xlim()`.